# Adding a file (image) to database with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a file `/tmp/image.jpg` that I want to upload into a BLOB field.

Can I read it the content with `file_get_contents` or I need a `fread` with `rb` (binary)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, you can. 
yes, you can.
yes, you can. (just to fill that stupid limit)

Answer (score 2):

a nice example is there http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It should work with file_get_contents. See a tutorial here:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Blobbing-Data-With-PHP-and-MySQL/